# How can I call local methods from functions in other classes

Tags: c#, nested-function

I have Two classes, "Shapes" which contains the shapes functions, and "Program", the main class

```
    public static double TriSides(double b, double h)
    {
        var res = b * h;
        return res;
    }

    public static double Circular(double diameter)
    {
        double SemiCirc(double radius)
        {
            return radius;
        }
        return diameter;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A program to generate a shape based on user input");

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Shapes n = new Shapes();
        Console.Write("Number of sides(1 - 4): ");
        Variables.userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        var input = Variables.userInput;
        if (input == "4")
        {
            Shapes.Quadrilaterals(Variables.inputNum, Variables.inputNum);
        }

        else if (input == "3")
        {
            Shapes.TriSides(Variables.inputNum, Variables.inputNum);
        }

        else if (input == "2")
        {
            //The nested function from the "Circular" function is supposed to be called here
        }

        else if(input == "1")
        {
            Shapes.Circular(Variables.inputNum);
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

I'm having trouble accessing the local method "SemiCirc" from the "Circular" method in the "Shapes" class

Comment: Did you have a specific reason to define that SemiCirc in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call local methods outside of the function they're defined in!

If you want to call the method then don't make it local, promote it to the class level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that method, because it is private to the method "Circular".

Answer (score 0):

Make semicircle public method and promote it to class level . As of now this is private, private can not be access outside of class.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straight forward way to invoke it.
However you can make use of reflection.

Inline is reference code . The name of method is retrieved via debugger.

```
else if (input == "2")
{
    //The nested function from the "Circular" function is supposed to be called here
    Type shapesType = typeof(Shapes);
    MethodInfo semiCircMethodInfo = shapesType.GetMethod(
        "<Circular>g__SemiCirc|1_0", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var retValue = semiCircMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { (object)6 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all local variables that are defined in the containing member, including its method parameters, are accessible in the local function.
make it public